# sharing git local repo on server without git

Tags: git, rstudio

I originally set up an Rstudio project with a local repository on a server that I cannot install git on.  This server is set up as a shared network drive, and the repository consists of R code and history.  I initiated the repository through the Rstudio interface, and I'm not sure of the details of how it was initiated.  I did make some changes to its basic configuration later when I began having HEAD problems and problems with git.ignore setup. I just got a new computer and this computer does not have full access to the repo.  From git bash on my new computer, I can see a single commit from about a year ago, and the Rstudio interface shows the project as not having any history.  Attempts to clone the repository from the new computer result in permissions errors. Attempts to share from the old computer meet with "I don't understand the manual" problems--what does this syntax look like?? 
Additional symptoms: When examining the git repo in RStudio, the contents of C:\Windows show up.

How can I set the repository up for sharing (with new computer)? I still have access to the old computer, and have set up both computers with the same username and have copied my public key (although I don't think it is actually used in the git setup in this instance--no ssh).

The constraints (mostly policy-related) are:
This repo must remain on the current network drive, and I can't install git on this server. I also can't pull files from the server to my computer--any branches and additional repos have to be kept on the network. All machines are running Windows 7.

Edit (problem explanation): 
The problem I thought I had involved something complicated to do with sharing and a repository set up on a server that did not have git installed on it.  The problem I actually had was that Windows cmd does not recognize UNC paths (and RStudio does not provide warnings to help people not in the know see what might be wrong).

The first symptom I noticed was that I could only view my history from the computer I initiated the repository from and not from a new computer.  After considerable digging, I realized there was a second problem: looking at the repository through the Rstudio interface showed only my C: drive.  I didn't realize these issues were related, but decided to try to at least get the repository properly mapped. I found something about UNC paths buried in a comment here: http://christianlemp.com/blog/2014/02/13/How-I-Manage-Data-Projects-with-RStudio-and-Git-Part-2.html

I changed the project shortcuts I had to use a mapped network drive rather than a UNC path, and my problems instantly resolved.

Comment: Your question is not really clear. You have a repository on a server on which cannot install git?! If you do not have git on the server, I am not sure why you call it a repository.

Comment: That's where all the files, history, etc. have to stay. I access them and update using git on my machine. Make somewhat more sense?

Comment: still can't understand what is your problem or what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think its possible to serve a git repository over the network without git installed. As a possible workaround, if the reason you cannot install git on the server is because you do not have root privileges, it is possible to install git from source - http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git (assuming the dependencies already exist on your server)

Once git is installed, you may access the git repo via SSH - http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols

Comment: Cannot install due to policy, not technical issues.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue I was having and edited the original question to contain additional symptoms useful in figuring it out.  It is not an issue with the network or git, but an issue with Windows cmd.  Windows cmd does not recognize UNC paths. Opening the project through a mapped network drive rather than a UNC path solves the problem.

Side note: It is possible to manage a git repository on a network drive that does not have git installed on it.